# Hard time parsing jsonp result

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is frustrating as hell. I'm getting a jsonp result cross domain that I can see coming across the wire.

my ajax function is

```
function loadPropertylatlon(propertyid) {
var mydata;

$.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    url: "/MapData.asmx/GetLatLonp",
    type: "POST",
    data: { id : propertyid },
    //async: false,
    cache: true,
    contentType: "application/json;",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { //
        mydata = data;
    },
    error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(xmlHttpRequest.responseText);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
        alert("Screen shot this error GetLatLon: " + jqXHR.toString() + " " + textStatus.toString() + " " + errorThrown.toString());
    }
});
return mydata;
}


// Load data from ajax        
latlondata = loadPropertylatlon(GetQueryStringParams('id'));
```

if I stringify data from the call I get this.

```
[{"lat":"25.555555","lon":"-80.555555","address":"1 main st, MIAMI, FL 33130","id":0,"count":0,"state":null}]
```

The problem I'm having is that if I attempt to access latlondata[0].lat I get nothing.

If I $.each the data in the ajax call like this

```
$.each(data, function (i, value) {
            console.log('Value of ' + i + ' is : ' + value);
            $.each(value, function (ii, vvalue) {
                console.log('obj Value of ' + ii + ' is : ' + vvalue);

            })
        })
```

I get an output of

```
Value of 0 is : [object Object]
obj Value of lat is : 25.854073
obj Value of lon is : -80.174575
obj Value of address is : 1105 ne 85th st, MIAMI, FL 33138
obj Value of id is : 0
obj Value of count is : 0
obj Value of state is : null
```

The issue is the data is not returning properly outside my function.

If I try to stringify this I get an undefined.

```
// Load data from ajax        
latlondata = loadPropertylatlon(GetQueryStringParams('id'));
// latlondata is undefined.. why?
alert(JSON.stringify(latlondata));
```

Comment: It works using your stringified results...  https://jsfiddle.net/ta2o2d6t/

Comment: The code works for me. Do you get any console errors? https://jsfiddle.net/05vjsoco/